# Tomcat 7 override context path

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

```
<Context path="/customers" docBase="/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myApp.war">

</Context>
```

Short of modifying this file in $Catalina_home$/conf/localhost by hand is there a way to set the path dynamically?  Via an environment variable would be ideal.
~

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename your WAR file to customers.war, place the WAR file in the appBase and with the default autoDeploy options you don't need the context.xml file above at all and the app is deployed at the required path.

Comment: I am trying to avoid that since I want an immutable container.  I might have rejigger the startup script to rename the war based on environment.  Ideally I would like to be able to pass an env variable to the context xml file.